# Having trouble mounting a 12TB Raid on Ubuntu Server

Tags: hard-drive, server.app, mac-pro, unix

I am running a Ubuntu server on my off of my 2008 MacPro, it runs great and works really well except I am not able to run any raid setups directly on it.

I have a large library that needs to be accessable from the web on my 12TB raid running raid 5...right now the drive is formatted as HFS+, however I can change the format to anything as long as it mounts to a MAC as Read Write.

At this point I have not been able to successfully mount the drive and was turning here for help.  I have tried so many solutions that it would probably be counter intuitive to mention all the methods I have tried so lets just imagine we are started from scratch.

Everything is up to date on Ubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Internal or external RAID? If external, how is it attached? FiberChannel?

Comment: Sorry good question, it is an external RAID attached via Firewire 800

Comment: and what type/model of external enclosure? "soft-raid"?

Comment: It is a G-Speed Q Raid http://www.g-technology.com/products/g-speed-q-4-bay-raid-16-tb

Again 12 TB Running Raid 5 which makes 8TB Usable

Comment: did you check the answer at [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write) especially answer Jan 31 '11 at 19:48 Steve Alfano?

Comment: Yes, this is my command `sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sbd1 /var/www/html/archive` and I get this error `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so`

I have confirmed that this is hfs+ several times

It should be noted that at this point as long as it mounts I am okay with Read-Access only, although I believe Journaling is turned off